# When try to modify a testcase in a Testplan that modifications are affecting to other testplan

Tags: testlink

I Created a new `Test Plan` With selecting the option : " **Create from Existing Test Plan** ".

All the test cases are added to the new test plan .When I am trying to Edit the test case or test suite  or delete any test case . That test case is deleted in the Previous test plan from where I imported test cases.

How can I only edit or Add/Delete the test cases without affecting the Other test plan?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your test case is unique and tracking back to the original test case which you don't want to edit/modify. 
What you have to do is copy and create a new one and edit that. This will then not have mapping to the original script written

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Observed and Its not only to TestLink specific.

1. Test cases are tracked by unique id
2. Those test cases may be part of different test plan
3. We take action as execution on Test plan
4. If we modify test case in any of the Test plan and if it differ from original, It will ask "Do you want to save/modify the original test case?"
5. When you don't want that test to be updated click on "NO". It will just update that particular test case from particular Test plan
6. If you are willing to modify click on "Yes". It will update the test case in all Test plan and original test case as well